# PostgreSQL Database Deployment

Tags: postgresql

It is know fact that backup and restore is a **slow** in Postgres
I'd like to deploy database to PostgreSQL server as fast as posible (Like it is possible in MS SQL just file copy and attach).

So If I:

1. backup and restore schema only.
2. And than copy database oid folder (data files) in to the appropriate oid ?

Will it work? 
of not what I also need to be consider.

Comment: No, it's not a known fact

Comment: Also: detaching a database in SQL Server is **not** "a backup"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "beginner" questions, but when there is a whole chapter on backup techniques in the official documentation and assorted blogs where they are demonstrated and compared this question seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work.

A database backup and restore can never be faster than copying the files is. So stop the database, copy the *complete cluster* and start PostgreSQL again. It won't get any faster.